# How to output multibyte unicode character?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

## What I want to do

I want to output superscript character in making a scientific report. It is like 'A/cm2'('2' in this case). I managed to find a character map in unicode shown below. As for this case superscript charcter of '2' is shown to be a 3-byte character.

[image: unicode character map]

## Environment

- Windows10 64bit
- Python v3.10.10

## What I did

I read the reference of Python ([description for chr function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)), I tried following command.

```
chr(0xe28282)
```

Python showed me following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "<stdin>" line 1 in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

How to describe to output a 3-byte character in Python ?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing several concepts (and probably the reason was the original site you used).

Unicode codepoint (or character) is given in the second line, and you should use that for `chr` in Python. The first line is the UTF-8 encoding (which can be derived from the second line). You can use it as binary string e.g. `b'\xe2\x82\x82'`.

But with Unicode (and sources in Python are by default UTF-8), you can directly use `"₂"`. It is much easier then going back and forth with tables. Let's your editor/GUI and Python do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you Giacomo,
Do you mean this description
 > b'\xe2\x82\x82'.decode()
is the answer ? 
But in command prompt on my Windows10, '.' (= it seems to be a dot) was shown. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Windows consoles are often not Unicode compatible (by default, but you can set them to use UTF-8, just legacy settings which causes so many problems). Note also `chr(0x2082)` is a possibility, or `"\u2082"`. For once, Python has too many options. I prefer the explicit (last one in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Giacomo. Correct answer was not shown in command prompt  but I could get correct answer on Power Shell when I inupt like 'chr(0x2082)' . It was just because command prompt does not support to show unicode input.

Answer (score 0):

`U+2082` is the Unicode code point you want.  Use an escape code, paste it directly into your code, or use `chr()` on the number:

```
>>> print('\u2082')
₂
>>> print('₂')
₂
>>> print(chr(0x2082))
₂
>>> ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(0x2070, 0x209d) if i not in (0x2072, 0x2073, 0x208f))
'⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎ₐₑₒₓₔₕₖₗₘₙₚₛₜ'
```

As of Python 3.3 Windows Unicode APIs are used to print to a cmd.exe window, so the encoding of the terminal won't matter, but you will need a font that supports the glyph; otherwise, you'll likely see the font's Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER (�).  All the characters above rendered correctly on Windows in the Chrome browser's font.

Above code was run from cmd.exe on Windows with Python 3.11.  The last eight characters from the `join` were rendered as replacement characters in the Consolas font I was using:

[image: Image of cmd.exe Consolas font output]

Ref: [Unicode.org: Superscripts and Subscripts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  Mark. It was a first time to hear that font file which supports such characters above is needed, but it is likely to be. By the way, why superscript '2' and '3' are not registered on this map ? In fact, I want to use '2' to output 'A/cm2'.

Comment: @kazutaka Superscript 1,2,3 already existed before in the latin-1 encoding that make up the first 256 Unicode code points.  they are U+00B9, U+00B2, and U+00B3 (`¹²³`).  See [Unicode.org: C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Mark. I understood. Let me close this question.